# Where in angular should I put this code?

Tags: angularjs

I have an http-method that gets some data from a google spreadsheet. I want to add this to the `$scope` so I can output it in the DOM. Later I might make a timed loop of this so that the $scope get's updated every 5 seconds or so.

I currently run the code in app.run:

```
angular.module('spreadsheet2angular', []).
run(function($http){
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://cors.io/spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/0Aq_23rNPzvODdFlBOFRYWlQwUFBtcXlGamhQeU9Canc/od6/public/values?alt=json'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            var entries = data.feed.entry;
            var phraces = [];
            entries.forEach(function(entry){
                var cell =  entry.gs$cell;
                if(!phraces[cell.row]){
                    phraces[cell.row] = {};
                }

                if(cell.col == 1)
                {
                    phraces[cell.row].name = cell.$t;
                }
                else if(cell.col == 2)
                {
                    phraces[cell.row].value = cell.$t;
                }
            });
            phraces.forEach(function(phrace){
                console.log(phrace);
            });
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error');
        });
    });
```

I'm new to angular, is this the best place to run it? I would like to run it as something that is easily reusable in different projects.

Answer (score 1):

I think from what you've explained, a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services) would be perfect. Build it out then inject it in your controller. You can then call/use that service object whenever you would like.

Answer (score 1):

I would use service/factory that returns promise. So we call async service method, get back promise and parse response into controller.

If you think to use the same call in the future, you can write generic method.

By the same way, if you are going to parse response by the same way in the future, the part of logic I would put into the service as well and wrap with `$q` . So the response still will be promise.

And this is an example I use that might help you to understand what I'm meaning:

```
app.service('apiService', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope',
        function($http, $q, $rootScope) {
                var request = function(method, data) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        var configHttp = {
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: config.api + '/' + method
                        };
                        if (data !== undefined) {
                                configHttp.data = data;
                        }
                        $http(configHttp).success(function(data, status, headers) {
                                if (data.error === undefined) {
                                        deferred.resolve(data);
                                } else {
                                        deferred.reject(data);
                                }
                        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
                                deferred.reject(data);
                        });
                        return deferred.promise;
                }

                return {
                        getItem: function() {
                                return request('get_item');
                        },
                        getItemByParams: function(id) {
                                return request('get_item_by_params', {id: id});
                        }
                };
        }
]);
```